# How to speed up this shell script

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am running this bash code from github in cygwin.This runs at the speed of 1 record per second. It is too slow and if I have a 10000 records, I need to wait a lot. Can I do anything to speed it up.

Source:https://github.com/lgpasquale/qchextractor

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -h|--help)
        echo "Extract the html documentation contained in a *.qch"
        echo "Usage:"
        echo "    qchextractor.sh <input-qch-file> <output-directory>"
        echo "Options:"
        echo "  -h, --help                  print this help"
        exit 0
    ;;
esac
done

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo "invalid input file: $1"
    exit 1
fi

output_dir="$2/html"
mkdir -p ${output_dir} || { echo "unable to create output dir $2"; exit 1; }

numfiles=$(sqlite3 "$1" "SELECT Count(*) FROM FileNameTable;")
echo "numero file: ${numfiles}"

maxrow=$(( ${numfiles} - 1 ))
echo -n -e "Extracting files:"
for row in $(seq 1 ${maxrow})
do
    echo -n -e "\rExtracting files: ${row}/${maxrow}"
    file_id=$(sqlite3 "$1" "SELECT FileId FROM FileNameTable LIMIT 1 OFFSET ${row};")
    file_name=$(sqlite3 "$1" "SELECT Name FROM FileNameTable WHERE FileId==${file_id};")
    dir_name=$(dirname "${file_name}")
    mkdir -p "${output_dir}/${dir_name}"
    sqlite3 "$1" "SELECT quote(Data) FROM FileDataTable WHERE Id==${file_id};" \
    | cut -d\' -f2 \
    | sed 's/^........//' \
    | xxd -r -p \
    | ./zpipe -d \
    > "${output_dir}/${file_name}"
#    | zlib-flate -uncompress \
done
echo -n -e "\n"
```

Comment: This is extremely hard to read.  Try using the snippet syntax.

Comment: Try joining your 3 SQL queries into one query. That's almost certainly the bottleneck.

Comment: Actually, there's no reason to do a separate query each time through the loop. Do one query with `LIMIT $maxrow`, and pipe the results into a `while read` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do the queries inside the loop. Do a single SQL query, and pipe its output to a loop that reads the results.

```
sqlite3 "$1" "SELECT Name, quote(Data) FROM FileDataTable LIMIT $maxrow" | 
    while read file_name data
    do
        dir_name=$(dirname "$file_name")
        mkdir -p "$output_dir/$dir_name"
        echo "$data" \
            | cut -d\' -f2 \
            | sed 's/^........//' \
            | xxd -r -p \
            | ./zpipe -d \
            > "${output_dir}/${file_name}"
    done
```

You might not even need `LIMIT $maxrow`. It looks like you're setting that to the number of rows in the table, and it was only needed because the loop is selecting a specific row each time. If you want to process the entire table, just leave that clause out. And then you don't need the query that sets `$numfile`.